# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in Android\Sdk

Tags: android, react-native, android-sdk-tools

When executing `react-native run-android` I am getting an error that is mentioned in multiple questions. However, none of the proposed solutions works for me.

I have android studio 3.5 installed on Windows 10.

The error is:
`Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

This is part of the log that seems related to the problem:

```
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 28 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" finished.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

I have the following defined as an env. variable:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

In this folder I have both `platform-tools` and `platforms`, and under `platforms` I have `android-28`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution, so I downgraded to android studio 2.3 and the problem is gone (downloaded it from https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/download/1500423. I see now that it is also available in https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).